# OpenAPI - How do I get a nested object property from a referenced schema?

Tags: openapi

Using "openapi": "3.0.1"

Response must be an application/json

```json
"responses": {
   "200": {
      "description": "Results",
         "content": {
            "application/json": {
               "schema": {
                 "$ref": "#/components/schemas/getArray"
               }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

My get call returns this array with objects like below:

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "Name": "Joe",
      "anotherItem": "Hello",
      "nestedObject": {
        "valueiWant": "foo",
        "valueidontcareAbout": "bar"
      }
   ]
}
```

My schemas are:

```json
"getArray": {
   "type": "object",
      "properties": {
         "result": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                  "Name": {
                     "type": "string"
                     ##this works and returns string "Joe"
                   },
                  "anotherItem": {
                     "type": "string"
                     ##this also works and returns string "Hello"
                     },
                  "nestedObject": {
                     "$ref": "#/components/schemas/gimmiewhatiWant" 
                     ##this gives me the entire nested object as a string in my application
                  }
                }
             }
         }
}
```

```json
"components": {
   "schemas": {
      "gimmiewhatiWant": {
         "type":"object",
         "properties": {
            "valueiWant": {
               "type": "string"
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

So I am trying to have it show me 3 strings, the 3rd being the property in the nested object per the gimmiewhatiWant schema above. I added the value I don't care about in the nested object in case that matters.

Expected strings:

```
Joe
Hello
foo
```

But instead I get strings:

```
Joe
Hello
"nestedObject": {"valueiWant": "foo","valueidontcareAbout": "bar"}
```

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here's the full OpenAPI description

If you want to return the following instance, you need to use an `allOf` in the `items` schema to pull out the `nestedObject` schema reference

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "Name": "Joe",
      "anotherItem": "Hello",
      "valueiWant": "foo"
      }
   ]
}
```

```json
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "title",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/thing": {
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Results",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/getArray"
                                },
                                "examples":{
                                    "test_example": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "result": [
                                                {
                                                    "Name": "Joe",
                                                    "anotherItem": "Hello",
                                                    "valueiWant": "foo"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "gimmiewhatiWant": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "valueiWant": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "getArray": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "result": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "allOf": [
                                {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "anotherItem": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/gimmiewhatiWant"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce your expected outcome.

```
Joe
Hello
foo
```

Comment: Tried adding "/properties/valueiWant" to where I am referencing the schema in "nestedObject" but it's still giving me the same ""nestedObject": {"valueiWant": "foo","valueidontcareAbout": "bar"}" result..

Comment: swagger editor says "definition was declared but never used in document". Wonder if it's being ignored as an object because it's in an array? Something with the types?

Comment: try that and see if it works.  You may have to play with your schema definitions a bit to get your desired behavior because if you have the `gimmewhatiWant` in a nested property, there's not much you can do to pull it out unless you discard that property.

Comment: Yeah I think it's my application refusing to point to that specific property in the array. Frustrating!